# How to refresh/repaint (on screen) the text of an element in long time cycles in javascript?

Tags: javascript, refresh, element, cycle

There is code

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script>
function longTimeFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
  //.do somethig
  }
}

function foo() {

  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = 'Start';
  console.log(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText);
  longTimeFunction(); // call long time

  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = 'First call complete';
  console.log(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText);
  longTimeFunction(); // call long time

  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = 'Second call complete';
  console.log(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText);

}

foo();
</script>
```

[In JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/denissaha/vptb2c3j/3/)

The text is written to the console at the correct intervals.

The text in the div element does not change.

Is it possible to change the text of a div?

I tried changing the style. I tried changing the display to "none" and then via setTimeout back to "block". Tried to add a child element. Also through setTimeout.

No result.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of "longTimeFunction()" is to simply cause some delay- then I would suggest making `foo()` an async function and `await`ing a promise from a `setTimeout` to cause an artificial delay.

```
async function foo(){
    console.log("foo called");
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    console.log("This message appears 1000ms after the first!");
}
```

Here is an example of that:

```js
    (async()=>{
        console.log("foo called");
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        console.log("This message appears 1000ms after the first!");
    })();
```

You can expand this out into it's own helper function to make this easy to call whenever you need a delay:

```
function delay(timeInMS) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeInMS));
}

async function foo(){
    // do some div stuff like your example
    await delay(2000) // wait for 2 seconds
    // do some more div stuff
    await delay(1000) // wait for 1 second
    // do the last div stuff
    

}
```

If you want `longTimeFunction()` to be called every x number of seconds, then simply invoke it inside of a `setInverval`

```
setInterval(someFunc,1000);
```

Here is an example of that:

```js
setInterval(()=>console.log("This is printed every 2 seconds!"),2000);
```

Comment: longTimeFunction() is not for delay of course. It's really a long function like ```$('.itemList .solved').show(); $('.itemList .unsolved').hide();```. If there are many such blocks, the function is executed for a long time (1-2 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're trying to achieve?

```js
function foo() {
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = 'Start';
  console.log(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText);

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = 'First call complete';
    console.log(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText);

    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = 'Second call complete';
      console.log(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText);
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
foo();
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: No, I don't need a delay. For example: 
```$(div).text("Seting all solved"); 
for(i=0; i<$('.manyOtherDivs').length; i++) { 
  if $('.manyOtherDivs').eq(i).hasClass('solved') {
    $('.yetAnoterDivs').eq(i).addClass('solved-also') ;
  }
}
$(div).text("Seting all UNsolved"); 
for(i=0; i<$('.manyOtherDivs').length; i++) { 
  if $('.manyOtherDivs').eq(i).hasClass('unsolved') {
    $('.yetAnoterDivs').eq(i).addClass('unsolved-also') ;
  }
}```

In this example text for div changed to 'Seting all UNsolved' AFTER function comleted. Not before.